# Message web pages to chrome apps

Tags: google-chrome-app, message-passing

How can I send message from my web page to my chrome app?

As chrome development website says, you can do this. but the only way that mentioned is just for extensions.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start looking for an answer here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/externally_connectable and on very similar page you pointed out: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage
This is very similar process to extensions and legacy apps.